# Building docker images if they don't exists on docker repository with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

What I am trying to do is if an image is not present on private docker repository then build that image from source code with docker-compose.

E.g.

```
version: '3.4'
  webapp:
    image: private_ecr_repo.amazonecr.com/webapp:latest
    build:
      context: "."
```

So when the image doesn't exists on private_ecr_repo, I'm looking to build it from local source.

PS: I have looked at `docker-compose build --pull` `docker-compose up --no-build` but they do not have the behaviour I am looking for .

From the documentation, when image attribute is used with build context in docker-compose file, the image attribute value denotes tags of built images. When build context is not mentioned, the image attribute acts as a reference to pull the docker image from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using overriding configuration feature of docker compose and defaulted to ecr images

I.e.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
  webapp:
    image: private_ecr_repo.amazonecr.com/webapp:latest
```

and when I wanted to build local images, I'd specify multiple docker-compose files

docker-compose.local.yml

```
version: '3.4'
  webapp:
    build:
      context: "."
```

with command `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.local.yml`

The second file adds build context and causes docker-compose to build locally

Answer (score 1):

You can't conditionally set things in the docker-compose file but what you could do is use [compose profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/)

```
version: '3.4'
  services:
    webapp:
      image: private_ecr_repo.amazonecr.com/webapp:latest
      profiles:
        - build
    webappbuild:
    build:
      context: "."
    profiles:
      - pull
```

Then you could do `docker-compose --profile pull up` or `docker-compose --profiles build up`

Comment: This would work, but would mean some duplication of compose config and different container names based on which profile is used